# Org files take a few seconds longer to open that text files do in Emacs on Windows

Tags: org-mode

I tend to prefer working with `org` files in Emacs. However, I have noticed that at least on Windows 10, Emacs (version 27.1) takes a few seconds longer to open an `org` file for the first time that it does opening a `txt` file, in which case it is almost instantaneous. I was wanting to know why this is the case and also if there was a way to have `org` files open as quickly.

Here is the profiler report:

```
- command-execute                                                  72  85%
 - call-interactively                                              72  85%
  - funcall-interactively                                          70  83%
   - dired-find-file                                               70  83%
    - find-file                                                    70  83%
     - find-file-noselect                                          70  83%
      - find-file-noselect-1                                       70  83%
       - after-find-file                                           69  82%
        - normal-mode                                              69  82%
         - set-auto-mode                                           69  82%
          - set-auto-mode-0                                        69  82%
           - org-mode                                              69  82%
            - org-load-modules-maybe                               42  50%
             - require                                             38  45%
              - byte-code                                          38  45%
               - require                                           35  41%
                - byte-code                                        33  39%
                 - require                                         29  34%
                  - byte-code                                      28  33%
                   - require                                       22  26%
                    - byte-code                                    21  25%
                     - require                                     17  20%
                      - byte-code                                  14  16%
                       - require                                   12  14%
                        - byte-code                                12  14%
                         - require                                  5   5%
                          - byte-code                               5   5%
                           - require                                1   1%
                              byte-code                             1   1%
                         - custom-declare-face                      1   1%
                          - face-spec-set                           1   1%
                           - face-spec-recalc                       1   1%
                            - make-face-x-resource-internal                  1   1%
                             - set-face-attributes-from-resources                  1   1%
                                set-face-attribute-from-resource                  1   1%
                   - custom-declare-face                            1   1%
                    - face-spec-set                                 1   1%
                     - make-empty-face                              1   1%
                      - make-face                                   1   1%
                       - make-face-x-resource-internal                  1   1%
                        - set-face-attributes-from-resources                  1   1%
                           set-face-attribute-from-resource                  1   1%
                 - custom-declare-variable                          1   1%
                  - custom-initialize-reset                         1   1%
                   - eval                                           1   1%
                    - funcall                                       1   1%
                     + #<compiled 0x26a2271>                        1   1%
            - byte-code                                            21  25%
             - require                                             14  16%
              - byte-code                                          10  11%
               - custom-declare-face                                3   3%
                - face-spec-set                                     3   3%
                 - face-spec-recalc                                 3   3%
                  - make-face-x-resource-internal                   3   3%
                   - set-face-attributes-from-resources                  3   3%
                    + set-face-attribute-from-resource                  3   3%
               - require                                            2   2%
                - byte-code                                         2   2%
                 - require                                          2   2%
                    byte-code                                       1   1%
               - custom-declare-variable                            1   1%
                - custom-initialize-reset                           1   1%
                 - eval                                             1   1%
                  - funcall                                         1   1%
                   + #<compiled 0x2190c65>                          1   1%
            - org-macro-initialize-templates                        3   3%
             - require                                              3   3%
              - byte-code                                           2   2%
                 require                                            1   1%
            - defconst                                              1   1%
             - org-version                                          1   1%
              - locate-library                                      1   1%
                 locate-file                                        1   1%
       - normal-backup-enable-predicate                             1   1%
          file-truename                                             1   1%
  - byte-code                                                       2   2%
   - read-extended-command                                          2   2%
    - completing-read                                               2   2%
     - completing-read-default                                      2   2%
      - read-from-minibuffer                                        2   2%
       - redisplay_internal (C function)                            1   1%
        - #<compiled 0x10be1df>                                     1   1%
           apply                                                    1   1%
- ...                                                              12  14%
   Automatic GC                                                    12  14%
```

Comment: "A few seconds" sounds excessive, but it depends on how big the file is, whether you are running with compiled Org mode (which is probably true) and whether there is anything in the file that Org mode has to preprocess (I can't think of anything, but...) The first thing I would do is [get a profile](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html#Profiling).

Comment: Add it to your question.

Comment: I have done that.

Comment: I think @jue's answer below is correct: the profile shows a lot of `require`s taking a significant amount of time. If you open the file again (or open a different file), that should not happen again and the file should open instantly - correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your question provides not enough information to be really sure, but:

> takes a few seconds longer to open an org file **for the first time**

This sounds like org is lazy loaded right in the moment you open an org-file for the first time.

This is easily achieved, by configuring `org` with `use-package` or a startet kit like `Doom`.

To verify if it is lazy loading, which kicks in, eval `M-: (require 'org) <RET>`, then load a org file for the first time. If loading is faster, then lazy loading is the culprit. Lazy loading is a good thing, btw.

Comment: I have not configured `org` for lazy loading. Loading the file after typing `M-: (require 'org) <RET>` makes little difference. The time lag is about the same. It is true that once, it has been loaded once it starts instantly after that.

Comment: Lazy loading is implicit with some options of use-package. By looking at your profiler report, I see multiple calls of `require`. This could mean other packages are lazy loaded too. It is not visible from your profiler report, which packages this are.

Comment: I only use  `use-package` for one or two packages. I do not have `org` configured for use with `use-package`. I don't think the lazy loading is the cause of the problem.